# When is conditional before_action method executed in Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In the following code, Why is `foo_enabled?` called for `EmployeeController.bar` ?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionControlelr::Base
    before_action :foo, if: :foo_enabled?
    def foo
        puts 'foo called'
    end

    def foo_enabled?
        puts 'sleep for 100s !'
        true
    end
end

class EmployeeController < ApplicationController
     skip_before_action :foo, only: [:bar]

     def bar
         puts 'inside bar'
     end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason is that once you start using conditions on your callbacks then the callbacks are always checked to see if they should run.

You'd think, quite reasonably, that the `skip_` would remove that callback from the callbacks for that action altogether. Instead, I think, it adds a condition to it. The `only:` condition adds a check something like `unless: Proc.new { action_name == 'bar' }`.

Depending on the order which the conditions get checked it is quite possible that your `foo_enabled?` condition gets checked before the `only:` condition which is why you see your method getting called. The code is iterating over the callbacks to check whether they should be run or not and the condition from `ApplicationController` is checked before the one added in `EmployeeController`.

The relevant code is in `lib/active_support/callbacks.rb` in the [`activesupport` gem](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activesupport) and in `lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb` in the [`actionpack` gem](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/actionpack). It's a bit hard (for me) to follow but I think what I've described is the essence of it.

Answer (score 1):

`foo_enabled?` is a condition of if `foo` should be called at all. 
It is then determined that `foo` should be called but `EmployeeController` skips it instead for `bar`.

If `foo_enabled?` returned `false` then there would be no `foo` action to execute and thus nothing to "skip".

Since the `before_action` is conditional based on the `if` the `if` must be evaluated first to determine if the action should fire.

After this determination is made then the `skip_before_action` evaluates if it should be skipped. Simplified work flow explanation:

```
#ApplicationController
if foo_enabled? 
  #EmployeeController
  if skip_action == :foo && !skip_action[:only].includes?(current_action)
    foo
  end
end
```